# Exo Player event listner callback

Tags: android, android-activity, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

in onPause() of activity i am passing false to player.setPlayerWhenReady(), i press home button of phone so onPause() of activity got called but i keep app in background, i am not removing from stack, after around 20 mins i re open the app so onStart() of activity got called where initialize exoplayer again and i pass valid video url, then i pass player.setPlayerWhenReady(true),but exo player directly calls onPlayerError() in its callback.. but when i close the app from stack and again open the app exo player works fine...please help to resolve this issue.

code is like this..

```
            simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
            simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();

            TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

            trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
            Log.d(AppConstants.LOG_TAG_LOG, "initializePlayer: player instance in initializePlayer is ="+player);
            simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
            Log.d(AppConstants.LOG_TAG_LOG, "initializePlayer: shouldAutoPlay is ="+shouldAutoPlay);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);


            DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(url), mediaDataSourceFactory,
                    extractorsFactory, null, null);

            durationSet = false;
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
            seekToValue = scSchedule.getSeekPosition();
            if (seekToValue != null) {
                player.seekTo(seekToValue);
            } else {
                player.seekTo(0);
                seekToValue = 0L;
            }
            player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
                        Log.d(AppConstants.LOG_TAG_LOG,
                                "In FullScreenVideoActivity::onPlayerStateChanged() ");
                        // increment videoViewCount in Analytics table
                        AppUtils.getInstance().updateAnalytics(false,
                                -1, true);
                        // update video watched duration in Analytics table
                        int videoViewDuration = 0;
                        if (seekToValue != null) {
                            if (filmDuration > seekToValue) {
                                videoViewDuration = (int) (filmDuration - seekToValue);
                                AppUtils.getInstance().updateAnalytics(false,
                                        videoViewDuration / 1000,
                                        false);
                            }
                        }
                        isVideoEnded = true;
                        videoEnded();
                        finish();
                    } else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY && !durationSet) {
                        filmDuration = (int) player.getDuration();
                        Log.d(AppConstants.LOG_TAG_LOG,
                                "In FullScreenVideoActivity::onPlayerStateChanged(), " +
                                        "filmDuration = " + filmDuration);
                        durationSet = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                    Log.d(AppConstants.LOG_TAG_LOG,"onPlayerError() called");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

                }
            });

   private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            shouldAutoPlay = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            player.release();
            player = null;
            trackSelector = null;
        }
    }
```

i call this release method in onDestroy() of activity.

Answer (score 2):

Problem might be because you are initialising Exoplayer again without releasing it first. 
It's usually a good practice to release the player in onPause as:

```
private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }
```

And then in onStart, you can initialise the player with the parameters where the user left.

```
private void initializePlayer() {
        if (player == null) {
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                    new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                    new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());

            playerView.setPlayer(player);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
            player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.media_url_mp3));
            MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
            player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
        }
```

P.S: Code is not related to yours. Its just an example.

Comment: i am releasing the player as per Exo player guidelines, it releasing player successfully but the issue is different, when i re open the app i initialize the player even after initializing the player and giving working video url, player throws an error, it calls onPlayerError() directly.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you call the release method in onDestroy, i suggest you try calling releasePlayer in onPause if `Util.SDK_INT <= 23` .. Or in onStop if `Util.SDK_INT>23`